# PageNumber / TotalPages on group header in report .rdlc

Tags: rdlc

I have a .rdlc report where I have no header (I have group headers)

I want to put the PageNumber on the group header.

If I use Globals!PageNumber I get this error:

The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox12.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[3]' refers to the global variable PageNumber or TotalPages. These global variables can be used only in the page header and page footer

Is there any way I could do this?

If there is no possibility to put this data on a group header...is there any possibility of overlap a header with the group header on a same line?

Answer (score 0):

Global variables [can't be used outside of the header/footer](https://forums.asp.net/t/1896636.aspx?How+to+get+Page+number+in+report+body+in+RDLC), as there is [no relationship between the header/footer and body areas](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ab9c18bc-ee37-45a2-a52d-628c12d08b33/ssrspagination-on-report-body?forum=sqlreportingservices). Therefore, there is no easy and precise way to display the page number in the body area.

However, as suggested by user Raymond-Lee in the second link, you can try to calculate it yourself by dividing a given row number by the total number of rows per page (and adding one if the page number will always be the first row). Nonetheless, this would take a bit of effort.

Comment: I can't calculate the number of rows per page as the height of a row is dynamic and can change due to the data

Comment: Then as told in the first link, or in some other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117527/displaying-page-number-in-body-of-rdlc), it would be impossible unless using a header/footer, and overlaping would not be possible, as the body [will hide the header content](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a2ecf91d-7120-453d-9b45-ea709c239dda/print-view-report-body-overlaps-with-page-header?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have the Page Header/Footer showing, then you can add items to it.  To show it, right click in the pale yellow area of the Layout view.  Then select Page Header and/or Page Footer, this will create another section on your report where you can add items.  Or, you can go to the Report menu option and enable the Page Header/Footer from there.

[link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1512fb04-973e-4144-bc33-cd917e51105c/globalspagenumber-amp-quot-of-quot-amp-globalstotalpages?forum=sqlreportingservices)